# How do I run logic on the second column in a pandas group?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I have a large dataframe grouped like so:

```
dates = frame['DATE'].unique()
test2 = frame.groupby(['NAME','DATE']).sum()

#NAME   DATE       VALUE
 AACT   20160602   186615450
        20160603   186615450
        20160604   186615450
        20160605   186615450
        20160606   186615450
        20160607   186615450
        20160608   186615450
        20160609   186615450
        201606010  186615450

 BAML   20160602   21900000
        20160603   21900000
        20160604   21900000
        20160605   21900000
        20160606   21900000
        20160607   21900000
        20160608   21900000
        20160609   21900000
        201606010  21900000
        201606011  21900000
        201606012  21900000
        201606013  21900000
        201606014  21900000
```

What I'm attempting to do here is take each group by the name key, and iterates each group's 'DATE' column through a logic check:

```
test2['STATUS'] = test2['DATE'].isin(dates).map({True:'Update',False:'Delete'})
```

So essentially the item 'ACCT' will have 'Delete's for anything after 20160610 since there are no values.

The above formula is not working and giving me a 'KeyError', I assume because I'm not correctly referencing the group.  How can I run this logic on each group item?

The desired output should be like so for every name group:

```
#NAME   DATE       VALUE      STATUS
 AACT   20160602   186615450  Update
        20160603   186615450  Update
        20160604   186615450  Update
        20160605   186615450  Update
        20160606   186615450  Update
        20160607   186615450  Update
        20160608   186615450  Update
        20160609   186615450  Update
        201606010  186615450  Update
        20160611              Delete
```

Comment: presumably `test2['STATUS'] = np.where(test2['DATE'].isin(dates), 'Update', 'Delete')` should work?

Comment: This is basically the same as my attempted logic, it returns a 'KeyError' as well since it's not referencing the group

Comment: can you try `idx = test2.index.get_level_values('DATE').to_series() test2['STATUS'] = np.where(idx.isin(dates),'Update','Delete')`